# VBA error when chinese characters are present in database table

Tags: excel, non-ascii-characters, vba

I have an excel application which connects to HANA database using ODBC and fetch table data in next sheet on button click. I am using below code to fetch data from database:-

```
Function importRoutine(sheet As String, provider As String, databaseschema As String, server As String, app As String, row As Long, column As Long, commandText As String, displayname As String, errorFlag As Boolean) As Integer
Debug.Print commandText
Dim l As QueryTable
Dim rs As Object
Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim iCols As Integer
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rcd = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim rangesheet As String
rangesheet = Sheets(sheet).Cells(row + 1, column).Address
Dim connectionsheet As String
connectionsheet = "Driver=" + provider + ";SERVERNODE=" + server + ";" + getAuthentication + "; CS=" + databaseschema + ""

cnt.ConnectionString = connectionsheet
cnt.Open

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnt
cmd.commandText = commandText
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText    

rcd.Open commandText, cnt '', adOpenStatic


Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
rs.ActiveConnection = cnt
rs.Open commandText, cnt   


   With Sheets(sheet).ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=3, Source:=rs, Destination:=Range(Sheets(sheet).Cells(row, column).Address)).QueryTable
    '.commandText = commandText
    '.CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCell
    .SavePassword = False
   .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .ListObject.Name = displayname
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


Sheets(sheet).ListObjects(displayname).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium10"
importRoutine = 0
Call deleteConnection


CloseRecordset:
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
CloseConnection:
cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing
      On Error GoTo 0


End Function
```

The code works fine if table contains english characters. But if the table has some special characters like some chinese characters, it is not able to put the data in next sheet and throwing error.

Is there any restriction on VBA not able to fetch/view data containing chinese characters?

Comment: What is the error, please? And what code is highlighted when it happens?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve that error. The issue was in data type of column in my table. It was varchar which was creating unicode error. When i changed the same to NVARCHAR, data fetch from database worked fine on the sheet for all the other language characters.